# When sending an email via C# SmtpClient, why does the recipient see the username and not the sender or from email?

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, gmail, smtpclient

When sending an email with SmtpClient, the email sends successfully but the recipient sees the username of the Smpt host as the sender and not the from or sender email specified in the MailMessage.

**Code**

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("from@email.com", "to@email.com");
mail.Subject = "subject";
mail.Body = "body";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Sender = "from@email.com";

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 587;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Host = smpt.gmail.com;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password");
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Send(mail);
```

The resulting email that is received displays username@gmail.com as the sender/from/reply-to address and not from@email.com.

Is it possible to display the from@email.com as the sender in the recipients email instead of username@gmail.com?

Comment: gmail doesn't allow re-direction using a different e-mail address.  They change the header to the address of the person sending it.

Comment: Thought it would be something like that. Any suggestions to achieve what I need - display the sender as the from@email.com?

Comment: You would have to go through a different e-mail provider than gmail.

Answer (score 1):

Many smtp providers will override your mail.Sender with client.Credentials in attempt to minimize phishing attacks and spamming in general. So, if you put president@bankofamerica.com in your mail.Sender you won't be fooling the recipient, as the recipient will see the client.Credentials instead.